# Can we find if element exists in an array {1,2,...,n} with elements m different elements in Θ(m)?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, linear-search

Suppose that we have an array `A[1...n]` and this array has ***m*** different keys.
Is it possible for `n→∞` the complexity to become `Θ(m)`?

Which means that if `m = constant` then `Θ(1)`.

Comment: @amit The array is not sorted. But i don't know if i can use it as a hypothesis,

Comment: I think you might get more responses to this question on the Theoretical Computer Science site, as it doesn't deal with coding issues.

Comment: Depends on how the array is stored. Or, to put it another way, if the question is "Is there a data structure whose size is O(n+m) which can store `n` ordered values in the range `1..m`, and which can answer in O(1) the queries "What is the value of object i?" and "Is there an object whose value is j?", then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.
Moreover, even if `m=2` you cannot find in `O(1)`, because that will imply you can find a value `x` in an unrestricted array (all values are possible) also in `O(1)`, by creating a function:

```
f(i) = 1         arr[i] = x
       0         otherwise
```

and searching if there is a value `i` such that `f(i) = 1`.

Since you cannot find in an array an element in `O(1)`, the knowledge of at most `m` distinct elements does not help you here.

The above is abviously true for any constant `m>2` as well.